# Axis2 - Creating complete binary distribution from source distribution

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, apache-axis

I have tried building the source distribution to generate the exact same binary distribution and have not been able to do so. I am using "mvn clean package" from command line and getting the jar under the /target and the .war under modules/webapp/target. I want all the executables present under/bin and the jar(s) under /lib as present in the binary distribution to be generated from source; in other words just the exact replica of the binary distribution from the source. Is it really possible to do so? If yes, can somebody please advice as how to proceed?

Comment: How are they different?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reproduce the zip or tar package correct?

You need to contact the project authors for that logic. Shouldn't be too mysterious, generally packaging code for different platforms is pretty mundane and relegated to separate downstream build tasks.

In the absence of this assistance you have two alternatives:

1. Alter your codebase to rely on the WAR file, used by the development users.
2. Change your verification process to rely on approved checksums, instead of binaries built in-house from source.

Building approved packages from source is a bit old fashioned, not because it's bad practice, but because it generally doesn't scale. My approach is to certify the development team that produces a build only trust binaries they sign and distribute. It's the same process applied to 3rd party closed source vendors, who deny me access to their source code in the first place :-)

Answer (score 0):

By default the binary distribution is not built. In order to build it, you have to enable the profile "everything":

```
mvn clean install -P everything
```

You will find it afterwards in .../modules/distribution/target